# Format dataframe in R and export to excel

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, openxlsx

I want to add the data-frame column names to the excel sheet I am exporting the data to. The first thing I wanted to do was to group the data by the group Column and add that group as a sub-header. I found this code on stack and was it added the sub-headers, but the column names from the original dataframe, besides 'Parameter', do not appear.

[image]

This is what I was trying

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Parameter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D"),
  Number = c('324', '173', '68', '396', 'NA', 'NA'),
  HC = c('0', '1.3', '5.8', '3.1', '58', '100'),
  Group = c('1', '1','2', '3', '3', '4')
)

# split into list  
dat$Group <- paste0("Group", dat$Group)
out <- split(dat[-4], f = dat$Group)
 

library(openxlsx2)
a
# custom helper function to write colored lists
wb_add_list <- function(wb, x) {
  wb <- wb$clone()
  row <- 1
  # Get column names of the input data
  col_names <- colnames(x[[1]])
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    # Add the original table headers only at the first row of the whole table
    if (i == 1) {
      wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = col_names, colNames = FALSE)
      wb$merge_cells(rows = row, cols = 1:length(col_names))
      dims <- paste0("A", row)
      wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("#ADD8E6")) # Light blue color
      wb$add_font(dims = dims, color = wb_color("white"))
      row <- row + 1L
    }
    wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = names(x[i]), colNames = FALSE)
    wb$merge_cells(rows = row, cols = 1:length(col_names))
    dims <- paste0("A", row)
    # Set the color of the header created by the Group column to #E7E6E6
    if (grepl("Group", names(x[i]))) {
      wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("#E7E6E6"))
    } else {
      wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("white"))
    }
    row <- row + 1L
    wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = x[[i]], colNames = FALSE)
    row <- row + nrow(x[[i]])
  }
  wb
}

# Add the colored list
wb <- wb_add_list(wb, out)

# Save the workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "colored_data.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

1. You should not merge the first two columns (commented line 28 in my example below)
2. colnames are a vector and in `openxlsx2` vectors are applied vertically (we treat them as a data frame column. (`t(col_names)` in line 27 in the example below).

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  Parameter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D"),
  Number = c('324', '173', '68', '396', 'NA', 'NA'),
  HC = c('0', '1.3', '5.8', '3.1', '58', '100'),
  Group = c('1', '1','2', '3', '3', '4')
)

# split into list  
dat$Group <- paste0("Group", dat$Group)
out <- split(dat[-4], f = dat$Group)


library(openxlsx2)

wb <- wb_workbook()$add_worksheet()

# custom helper function to write colored lists
wb_add_list <- function(wb, x) {
  wb <- wb$clone()
  row <- 1
  # Get column names of the input data
  col_names <- colnames(x[[1]])
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    # Add the original table headers only at the first row of the whole table
    if (i == 1) {
      wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = t(col_names), colNames = FALSE)
      # wb$merge_cells(rows = row, cols = 1:length(col_names))
      dims <- paste0("A", row,":C", row)
      wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("#ADD8E6")) # Light blue color
      wb$add_font(dims = dims, color = wb_color("white"))
      row <- row + 1L
    }
    wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = names(x[i]), colNames = FALSE)
    wb$merge_cells(rows = row, cols = 1:length(col_names))
    dims <- paste0("A", row)
    # Set the color of the header created by the Group column to #E7E6E6
    if (grepl("Group", names(x[i]))) {
      wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("#E7E6E6"))
    } else {
      wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("white"))
    }
    row <- row + 1L
    wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = x[[i]], colNames = FALSE)
    row <- row + nrow(x[[i]])
  }
  wb
}

# Add the colored list
wb <- wb_add_list(wb, out)

# wb$open()
```